# looking for a chinese simplified fonts which unable to find under the default fonts in Words

Tags: simplified-characters

are there free fonts for simplified chinese that I can download?  I have some default fonts but not the one I want.  I want to explore more fonts.

Answer (score 1):

You might download Noto Sans CJK and Noto Serif CJK.

https://www.google.com/get/noto/help/cjk/

Choose SC version (SC for simplified Chinese)

Comment: actually I am looking for cursive / calligraphy simplified chinese fonts

Comment: What kind of "free" do you expect? Does it mean no license restriction for commercial use, or no need to pay any money, or else?

Answer (score 0):

Get [Simsun](https://www.wfonts.com/font/simsun), it is used everywhere.

For other fonts, just search 'free chinese fonts' to find hundreds of different fonts.

Example [here](https://www.freechinesefont.com/).

Answer (score 0):

There is a [list](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CJK_fonts) of almost all CJK fonts in wikipedia.